# How to run dependency Jobs on PCF?

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have two batch applications ex: batchapp1 and batchapp2 . I want to run batchapp2 after completion of the batchapp1. Can we achieve it using PCF scheduler or can we achive it using Spring data-flow-server?

Right now we are doing it using Control-M  and run on VM's JVM (Not on cloud).

Answer (score 1):

What you need is Spring Cloud Data Flow's [Composed Task](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-composed-tasks) functionality. With this, you'd be able to orchestrate a series of Tasks/Batch-Jobs as Direct Acyclic Graph. A graph can include sequential, parallel, or both where each of the steps is a Task/Batch-job.

For your example, in SCDF, the [DSL representation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_composed_tasks_dsl) would look like:

> task create foo --definition "batchapp1 && batchapp2"

Upon launching the Task definition `foo` in SCDF on PCF, it would launch `batchapp1` first and upon success/failure, it would run the `batchapp2` next. You can also have transitions to run cleanup/error-handling steps based on the exit-code at each step.

As an alternative, you could do all this on the interactive drag & drop visual canvas, too.

Also to note, in PCF, all the steps would be launched as short-lived CF Tasks, which run for a finite time. That would be them running as long as the App needs to run and then it is cleanly shutdown to free-up resources.

Comment: Thanks Anandan. We have >600 batch Jobs like this. Can we deploy all these jobs in one SCDF or we need to allocate one SCDF for 50 jobs?   Note: all these jobs are scheduled at different time.

Comment: SCDF is a lightweight Boot App. Apart from the orchestration and simple metadata in the backing database, there's nothing to worry about in regards to resources. A single instance should be enough. If you're running SCDF on PCF, a minimum HA config could be advisable, though. Perhaps 2 or 3 instances just to cover failover scenarios. PCF would attempt to restart the App if and when it fails anyway.